# How to set PresentingViewController with current ViewController in iOS 7+

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

In my iOS 7+ app I'm using the latest version of Harpy, which perform an app version check and present an alert if there's a new version of my app available in the App Store.

Due to the structure of my app, I'm facing this issue in the debugger:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x144538530> on <DCLoginViewController: 0x14460c1a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

this is because harpy is configured in the AppDelegate and has a parameter that define the presentingViewController:

```
[[Harpy sharedInstance] setPresentingViewController:_window.rootViewController];
```

I believe the issues arise because my app check if the user is already logged in, if so, instead of presenting the DCLoginViewController, it jumps to the next view which is "LoadingViewController".

How can I set the presentingViewController to be this LoadingViewController or even the ViewController currently on screen at execution time?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to launch **Harpy** in the `AppDelegate`. You can launch it after `LoadingViewController` has loaded. It's only recommended to launch it in the `AppDelegate` as the idea is to show the alert as soon as the app is loaded. It's more of a UX thing than anything else.